# snakemake PICARD merge bam files

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake, snakeyaml

I am new in using snakemake, I have an issue when using PICARD MergeSamFiles to merge bam files into one bam files. I would like to merge 1_sorted.bam 2_sorted.bam ...10_sorted.bam into one bam file with directory name.

```
import snakemake.io 
import os.path

PICARD="/data/src/picard.jar"
(SAMPLES,)=glob_wildcards("bam/{sample}_sorted.bam")
NAME=os.path.dirname

def bam_inputs(wildcards):
    files = expand("bam/{sample}_sorted.bam", sample=SAMPLES)
    INPUT = "I="+files 
    return INPUT

rule all:
    input: "bam/{NAME}.bam"

rule merge_bams:
    input: bam_inputs
    output: "bam/{NAME}.bam"
    params: mrkdup_jar="/data/src/picard.jar"
    shell: "java -Xmx16G -jar {params.mrkdup_jar} MergeSamFiles \
    {input} \
    O={output} \
    SORT_ORDER=coordinate \
    ASSUME_SORTED=false \
    USE_THREADING=true"
```

Error:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
WildcardError in line 12 of /data/data/Samples/snakemake-example/WGS-test/step3.smk:
Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files:
'NAME'
```

I don't know how to merge all bam files into one and don't know how to set the directory name as a variable to the final bam file. Please advice.

UPDATE:

```
import snakemake.io

PICARD="/data/src/picard.jar"
(SAMPLES,)=glob_wildcards("bam/{sample}_sorted.bam")
#NAME=os.path.dirname
NAME="test"

rule all:
    input: "bam/{name}.bam".format(name=NAME)

rule merge_bams:
    input: expand("bam/{sample}_sorted.bam",sample=SAMPLES)
    output: "bam/{name}.bam".format(name=NAME)
    params: mrkdup_jar="/data/src/picard.jar"
    shell: """java -Xmx16G -jar {params.mrkdup_jar} MergeSamFiles \
    {"I=" + input} \
    O={output} \
    SORT_ORDER=coordinate \
    ASSUME_SORTED=false \
    USE_THREADING=true """

ERROR:

RuleException in line 11 of /data/data/Samples/snakemake-example/WGS-test/step3.smk:
NameError: The name '"I=" + input' is unknown in this context. Please make sure that you defined that variable. Also note that braces not used for variable access have to be escaped by repeating them, i.e. {{print $1}}

MergeSamFiles \
I= sub1_sorted.bam I=sub2_sorted.bam I=sub3_sorted.bam \
O= sub.bam \
SORT_ORDER=coordinate \
        ASSUME_SORTED=false \
        USE_THREADING=true
```

Comment: I don't know much snakemake but I think `"I="+files ` just adds a `I=' to a list of files while you need to add a suffix `I=` to EACH bam files. Another solution is to create a file with the required `.list` suffix containing the path to the BAMs and to use `I=my.list`

Comment: your first problem is that `NAME` is not a string:`import os`, `NAME=os.path.dirname`, `NAME`, `<function dirname at 0x7f6e0e4ab7b8>`
`

Comment: You need to define wildcard `{NAME}` in `rule all` so that snakemake knows the expected [target files](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#targets) to be created. This is what the error message is pointing to.

Comment: Now you may see the error even in the syntax highlighting of stackoverflow. You have no closing quote in the line 12.

Comment: Oh thanks. how can I add the "I=" in every input *_sorted.bam in snakemake input

Comment: Does `"I=".join(input)` work?

Comment: shell: """java -Xmx16G -jar {params.mrkdup_jar} MergeSamFiles \
    {"I=" + .join(input)} \
    O={output} \
    SORT_ORDER=coordinate"""  like this in shell ? didn't work same error

Comment: Not `"I=" + .join` but `"I=".join(input)`.
Anyway, that wouldn't work :). Try `" ".join(["I=" + s for s in input])` If the string wouldn't concatenate with the item from input, even more straightforward solution: `" ".join(["I=" + str(s) for s in input])`

Comment: RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 15 of /data/data/Samples/snakemake-example/WGS-test/step3.smk:
Command ' set -euo pipefail;  java -Xmx16G -jar /data/src/picard.jar MergeSamFiles " ".join(["I=" + s for s in input])     O=bam/test.bam     SORT_ORDER=coordinate     ASSUME_SORTED=false     USE_THREADING=true ' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Pay special attention to the fact that I made the string an f-string. This means that the expression in {} will be evaluated first, and the expressions in {{}} will be substituted with the expressions from snakemake.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193968/discussion-between-dmitry-kuzminov-and-peter-chung).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's regard the `rule all`. You need to show the snakemake what file you actually expect to build as a target. No wildcards: just something unambiguous. You said it should be a bam file with directory name?

```
rule all:
    input: f"bam/{NAME}.bam"
```

Note that using the f-string I converted the `{NAME}` from a wildcard into an exact string value that comes from the variable `NAME`. You may choose any other way to do that, i.e. `"bam/{name}.bam".format(name=NAME)`

Next, keep in mind that now `{NAME}` in the "all" rule and `{NAME}` in the "merge_bams" rule are different entities, so they have nothing in common. Moreover, the wildcard doesn't necessary equal to the `NAME` variable that you defined on the line 6. I would call the wildcard somehow differently to avoid misunderstanding.

One more thing: I'm not sure what you are doing in the `bam_inputs` function:

```
INPUT = "I="+files
```

The result of the expand function should be enough to specify the input for the merge_bams rule. If you need to add "I=" for every file in the list, try to do it right in the `shell:` section:

```
rule merge_bams:
    input: bam_inputs
    output: "bam/{NAME}.bam"
    params: mrkdup_jar="/data/src/picard.jar"
    shell: f"""java -Xmx16G -jar {{params.mrkdup_jar}} MergeSamFiles 
        {" ".join(["I=" + s for s in input])} 
        O={{output}} 
        SORT_ORDER=coordinate 
        ASSUME_SORTED=false 
        USE_THREADING=true"""
```

Comment: import snakemake.io

PICARD="/data/src/picard.jar"
(SAMPLES,)=glob_wildcards("bam/{sample}_sorted.bam")
#NAME=os.path.dirname
NAME="test"

rule all:
    input: "bam/{name}.bam".format(name=NAME)

rule merge_bams:
    input: expand("bam/{sample}_sorted.bam,sample=SAMPLES)
    output: "bam/{name}.bam".format(name=NAME)
    params: mrkdup_jar="/data/src/picard.jar"
    shell: """java -Xmx16G -jar {params.mrkdup_jar} MergeSamFiles \
    {"I=" + input} \
    O={output} \
    SORT_ORDER=coordinate \
    ASSUME_SORTED=false \
    USE_THREADING=true """

Comment: But ERROR:
SyntaxError in line 12 of /data/data/Samples/snakemake-example/WGS-test/step3.smk:
EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: bam_inputs: I want to make a list of all the bam files in that directory and then merge them. I changed to expand("bam/{sample}_sorted.bam,sample=SAMPLES)

Comment: @PeterChung The error is a syntax problem. Unfortunately the comment doesn't allow proper formatting, so it is impossible to check the syntax. Please put that code as an update to the question. And please describe which line has the number 12.